# How to add a HTML partial without a component inside a view in Angular2

Tags: html, angular

I have a component and its HTML file.

**component:**

**hello-world.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'hello-world',
  templateUrl: 'hello-world.html'
})
export class HelloWorld {
  yourName: string = '';
}
```

**Template:**

**hello-world.html:**

```
<label>Name:</label>

<h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
```

Now, I have other html `template.html` which has no component, for example it contain,

**template.html**

```
<h1>Welcome to template file</h1>
<p> This is an example file </p>
```

**Now, I wanted to include `template.html` file in the `hello-world.html`. How can I do that.**

In Angular1 I used to do,

```
<div ng-include src="'template.html'"></div>
```

How can I do it in Angular2? I am very new to Angular2.

I searched this question in many places, every one is giving an answer which has components. but didn't get my required solution.

Answer (score 3):

Short: isn't possible yet out of the box.

You could create a `Directive` like old `ng-include` which will do the work for you..
That `Directive` would load the html-file and then paste it to the DOM